# How To Load wp_add_inline_styles

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm using this PHP code to modify default CSS inline via functions.php however its not working.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'inline_bar_width' );

function inline_bar_width() {

    if ( is_category( 'ratings' ) ) {

        $theme_version = wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' );

        $bar = bar_width();

        $css = '';

        $css .= sprintf(
            '.bar {width: %s%%;}',
            $bar
        );

        if ( $css ) {
            wp_add_inline_style( $theme_version, $css );
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried wrapping `wp_enqueue_scripts` in different hooks but it doesn't work.

I'm working via child theme using this to load parent styles

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_parent_styles' );
function child_enqueue_parent_styles() {

       wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
```

**Update :** The value for the width is not changing using this code. It's supposed to control the width based on the PHP code. $bar returns a width. The problem has something to do with using `wp_add_inline_style( 'twentytwenty', $css );` in a twenty twenty child theme or the way i'm using it on based on this code.

Comment: Why would you add CSS footer? That’s just a recipe for causing layout shifts.

Comment: Looking thru the suggested solutions, some suggest trying to load inline styles in the footer.

Comment: Solutions for what?

Comment: Maybe using $theme_version as the handle is wring! Maybe i should use the child theme or parent theme handle.

Comment: Well that’s what the documentation says. You still haven’t said what problem you’re trying to solve.

Comment: Update : The value for the width is not changing using this code. It's supposed to control the width based on the PHP code. $bar returns a width.

Comment: [Search and research before asking the question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). See the first parameter of  [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/). It is the script handle, not the theme version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add enqueue your child themes style sheet as well

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'inline_bar_width' );
function inline_bar_width() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwenty-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

if ( is_category( 'ratings' ) ) {

    $bar = bar_width();

    $css = '';

    $css .= sprintf('.bar {width: %s%%;}', $bar );

    if ( $css ) {
        wp_add_inline_style( 'twentytwenty-style', $css );
    }
  }
}
```